# How to add an after hook to a rake task (e.g. ordering db/schema.rb after db:migrate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

How to add an after hook to `rake db:migrate`?

e.g. adding some post-ordering to `db/schema.rb`, normalize `db/schema.rb`, using rubocop to clean the syntax of `db/schema.rb`, etc. (just examples, but basically anything after db:migration)

Answer (score 0):

```
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  load Rails.root.join('bin', 'your-script')
end
```